# Powershell script for deleting users off of a computer

Tags: windows, powershell, automation, scripting, active-directory

I have written up a script that gives me the ability to delete multiple user profiles and the registry keys associated off of a computer. this is for work, multiple people share computers at a few clinics of ours and eventually the computer gets filled up of user profiles of people that no longer work there or just got their own computer. so the storage ends up running out, thats where i come in, deleting a lot of the user profiles to clean up the disk. i wanted to make this a lot easier so i tried writing a script. here it is. btw this is all domain join. this can be done by group policy i'm aware but my engineers haven't made that happen, i'm just help desk trying to make my life easier.

```
$profiles = Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_UserProfile
$users = 'schaudhary'
foreach ($profile in $profiles){
    if ($profile.Special -ne 'True'){
        if ($profile.LocalPath.split('\')[-1] -notcontains $users) {
            $profile | Where-Object { $_.LocalPath.split('\')[-1] } | Remove-CimInstance -WhatIf
            Write-Host "deleting" $profile.LocalPath
        }
    }
}
```

problem is when i try to exclude multiple users from the deletion process, it doesn't work. but when i have just one user, like right now "schaudhary" it'll work (it'll exclude schaudhary). how can i make it exclude multiple users?? I have to exclude the local admin acct, the active users on the machine and some special service accounts. and if anyone can give tips on adding last use time included in here that'll help. so only delete if user is 90 days old or more, something like that.

Comment: How are you defining multiple users?

Answer (score 1):

an event associated with a user would mean that he was working on a computer.
But you have to make sure there are logs for 90 days

```
$sid =(Get-adUser $username).sid.value
$StartDate = (Get-Date) - (New-TimeSpan -Day 90)
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{LogName='Security';data=$sid;StartTime=$StartDate} -MaxEvents 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You are reversing the variables when using `-notcontains`..

Its use is `$collectionOfThings -contains $singleThing` or
`$collectionOfThings -notcontains $singleThing`.

Since PowerShell  version 3, you can also do the reverse using `-in` and `-notin` as in
`$singleThing -in $collectionOfThings` or the negation of that
`$singleThing -notin $collectionOfThings`.
<sup>See [Containment operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.3#containment-operators)</sup>

Try

```
$profiles = Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_UserProfile
$users    = @('schaudhary')  # array of profiles to keep
foreach ($profile in $profiles){
    if (!$profile.Special) {
        $userName = $profile.LocalPath.split('\')[-1]
        # or: 
        # if ($userName -notin $users) {
        if ($users -notcontains $userName) {
            if (!$profile.Loaded) {
                $profile | Remove-CimInstance -Confirm:$false -WhatIf
                Write-Host "Deleting $($profile.LocalPath)"
            }
            else {
                Write-Warning "Profile $($profile.LocalPath) is currently loaded.."
            }
        }
    }
}
```